# how can i stop insert data when refresh page with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i need to stop insert data when refresh page
iam new in codeigniter and can't do redirect easly,please support
view:pages/home.php view which has a form

```
<html>
<head></head>
</body>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('speed/insert_to_db'); ?>

Branch: <input type="text" name="branch" /><br/>
Business Unit: <input type="text" name="buinessUnit" /><br/>
Device Type: <input type="text" name="deviceType" /><br/>
Brand: <input type="text" name="brand" /><br/>
Device Model: <input type="text" name="deviceModel" /><br/>
SN: <input type="text" name="SN" /><br/>
status: <input type="text" name="status" /><br/>
department: <input type="text" name="department" /><br/>
username: <input type="text" name="username" /><br/>
notes: <input type="textarea" name="notes" /><br/>
computername: <input type="text" name="computerName" /><br/>
Save:<input type="submit" name="save" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

model:add_model 
model which has insert_to_db function

```
       public function insert_into_db(){
           $post=$this->input->post();
           if(!isset($post['save'])) return;
           $data=array('Branch'=>$post['branch'],'BusinessUnit'=>$post['buinessUnit'],'DeviceType'=>$post['deviceType'],'Brand'=>$post['brand'],'DeviceModel'=>$post['deviceModel'],'SN'=>$post['SN'],'Status'=>$post['status'],'Departmant'=>$post['department'],'UserName'=>$post['username'],'Notes'=>$post['notes'],'ComputerName'=>$post['computerName']);
           $this->db->insert('hardware_assets', $data);
return $this->db->insert_id(); // if using mysql
       }
}
```

controller:

```
<?php

class Speed extends CI_Controller {

        function insert_to_db()
           {

             $this->load->model('add_model');

             $this->add_model->insert_into_db();
             $this->load->view('pages/home');//loading success view

           }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

use $this->input->post('input_name') instead of raw code & check form submission in controller. i.e

```
<?php

class Speed extends CI_Controller {

    function insert_to_db()
       {

         $this->load->model('add_model');
         if($this->input->post('save')){
            $this->add_model->insert_into_db();
            $this->load->view('pages/home');//loading success view
         }


       }
}
```

also remove `if(!isset($post['save'])) return;` from model

Comment: my code insert data successfull but when refresh insert one again

Comment: have you test my code? It will never insert data unless you press "Save" button

Comment: ya,it still insert data when refresh

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I wouldn't have any `$post` or `$get` data in a model. It can be done like this with CI, however, it is much more standard practice to get the data in the controller, validate it and then pass it through to the model.

Secondly, look through the documentation for the [Form Validation Library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html)

It gives some nice, simple examples of how of how to handle form submissions as well.

The easiest way to stop form resubmissions, IMO, is to redirect after you've got all the data from the submission. You can use the `redirect()` function from the [url_helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html) file to do this.

Hope this helps!